# Rails 3 - custom ajax action is not working

Tags: ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, custom-action

I want to create a custom action in Rails which will update views and print some info on div.

I use that gem for file upload:
https://github.com/valums/file-uploader/blob/master/client/fileuploader.js

After successful upload I want to update with ajax page how many miliseconds it takes.

In old Rails I would write that with:

```
def set_tab
  @diff = count_miliseconds_method
  render :update do |page|
    page.replace_html "place_menu", render( :partial => 'place_menu')
  end
end
```

But I cant figure out how to do that in Rails 3.1.

My custom action controller code:

```
def custom
  [...] # Here everything works OK
  start_time = Time.now
  Some_method
  end_time = Time.now
  @diff = ((end_time - start_time)*100).to_i # counted miliseconds
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json {render :json => {:success => true, :time => @diff}, :status => :created, :location => custom_words_path}
  end
end
```

My custom.js.erb code

```
var el = $('#upload-log');
el.append("#{@diff} ms");
```

Unfortunately this doesnt work. I get response e.g.
`{"success":true, "time":324}`
 but js.erb file doesnt get executed and page doesnt containt information about miliseconds.

Any idea how to fix that?

**Update**

Github repo:
https://github.com/there-is-no-spoon/Anagram

Answer (score 1):

You're returning JSON now (in Rails 3.1) not a chunk of string containing Javascript (as was the case before).

You need to write your code which handles your result where you make the Ajax Call. I assume you're using jQuery. So where you make the Ajax call, implement the success handler and do the

```
var el = $("#upload-log"); 
...
```

stuff there.

Basically server does not return Javascript anymore, it is completely on the client side only.

You need to implement the onComplete method of your file upload plugin. Read the manual of your js plugin, its mentioned clearly.

Answer (score 1):

To execute js.erb file you have to pass

```
:format => :js
```

to your path generating method - for example:

```
link_to "My custom action", my_action_path(:format => :js)
```

Comment: Ups. So it is bigger problem, because I call that action through JS plugin.. Here is the code: https://github.com/there-is-no-spoon/Anagram/blob/master/app/views/words/index.html.erb

Comment: Read the js manual. U need to implement the onComplete event handler for the file uploader.

Comment: I think it would be enough to change action to /words/uploader.js. But @AdityaSanghi suggestion is also ok - you can achieve what you want with onComplete handler.